# Spring Boot not serving static content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I can't get my Spring-boot project to serve static content.

I've placed a folder named `static` under `src/main/resources`. Inside it I have a folder named `images`. When I package the app and run it, it can't find the images I have put on that folder.

I've tried to put the static files in `public`, `resources` and `META-INF/resources` but nothing works.

If I jar -tvf app.jar I can see that the files are inside the jar on the right folder:
`/static/images/head.png` for example, but calling: `http://localhost:8080/images/head.png`, all I get is a `404`

Any ideas why spring-boot is not finding this? (I'm using 1.1.4 BTW)

Comment: Have enabled spring boot auto-configuration?

Comment: The default resource handling maps to /**. I'd double-check that it's enabled. If it is, you'll see a line that ends with "Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]" in the output when you start your app. Another possibility is a controller of your own that's also mapped to /** and is taking precedence over the resource handler. Posting the output of your app's startup would make it easier for us to see what's going on.

Comment: I'm guessing you have `@EnableWebMvc` (or equivalent) in your app. That would switch off the default Boot MVC config.

Comment: Nope, I don't have @EnableWebMvc anywhere. I don't get this. Now its happening with templates as well. Any of my templates (freemarker) are being found by the classloader of spring boot.

Comment: @DaveSyer great tip man! It saved me a headache! Turned out that exactly this annotation (leftover from migration to Boot) screwed up things for me. Thanks!

Comment: I am running into a similar issue and have had no luck with any of the recommended resolutions provided. If someone could be so kind to take a look and point out exactly what it is I am doing wrong it would be much appreciated!!! https://github.com/kylebober/kbss

Comment: I found that if I have a file src/main/resources/public/style.css, then the url for that is /style.css and not  /public/style.css as I expected.

Comment: webapp ended up being the folder that worked for me to serve static content with no hassle.

Comment: Can you check your application.properties file value of this server.servlet-path=<myapp>, and change your url to http://localhost:8080/<myapp>/images/head.png

Comment: Refer to https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/modular

Comment: @AndyWilkinson 2nd comment - I had a controller with mapping to "/". Which was the problem.

Comment: OP, my answer is clearly the most popular :) It'd be nice if you accepted it, that way you show some appreciation for the effort, and the question would be rated higher in SO search results (I think), thus allowing people to find it more easily.

Comment: please find an answer @ [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38788459/spring-boot-static-content-with-context-path/54112835#54112835)

Comment: If this happens in the final runtime, double-check that you have the parent of the `static`, `public` or whatever resource dir on the classpath!

Comment: I have more than 50 controller class in my project, for all controller APIs are working fine but for one particular controller all APIs are giving error as 
{
    "type": "about:blank",
    "title": "Not Found",
    "status": 404,
    "detail": "No static resource ",
    "instance": ""
} 

even though, by all such APIs not accessing any static resource. Its same as normal CURD operation API.

Answer (score 213):

Not to raise the dead after more than a year, but all the previous answers miss some crucial points:

1. `@EnableWebMvc` on your class will disable `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration`. That's fine if you want complete control but otherwise, it's a problem.
2. There's no need to write any code to add another location for static resources in addition to what is already provided. Looking at `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ResourceProperties` from v1.3.0.RELEASE, I see a field `staticLocations` that can be configured in the `application.properties`. Here's a snippet from the source:

   ```
   /**
    * Locations of static resources. Defaults to classpath:[/META-INF/resources/,
    * /resources/, /static/, /public/] plus context:/ (the root of the servlet context).
    */
   private String[] staticLocations = RESOURCE_LOCATIONS;
   ```
3. As mentioned before, the request URL will be resolved **relative** to these locations. Thus `src/main/resources/static/index.html` will be served when the request URL is `/index.html`. The class that is responsible for resolving the path, as of Spring 4.1, is `org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver`.
4. Suffix pattern matching is enabled by default which means for a request URL `/index.html`, Spring is going to look for handlers corresponding to `/index.html`. This is an issue if the intention is to serve static content. To disable that, extend `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` (but don't use `@EnableWebMvc`) and override `configurePathMatch` as shown below:

   ```
   @Override
   public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
       super.configurePathMatch(configurer);

       configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
   }
   ```

IMHO, the only way to have fewer bugs in your code is not to write code whenever possible. Use what is already provided, even if that takes some research, the return is worth it.

**Edit July 2021:**

4. `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` has been deprecated since Spring 5. Implement `WebMvcConfigurer` and annotate with `@Configuration`.

Comment: And don't extend `DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration` which has the same effect as using `@EnableWebMvc`

Comment: How to counter "Spring Boot adds [@EnableWebMvc] automatically when it sees spring-webmvc on the classpath"? No way to not use @EnableWebMvc in that case.

Comment: _the only way to have fewer bugs in your code is not to write code[...]_ really like this.

Comment: Hmm.. I've tried to apply this but [it's still not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48934844/index-html-is-not-showing-up-after-refactoring-the-project).

Comment: `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` is deprecated.

Comment: I agree that not having @EnableWebMvc is probably best in this case but Spring Auto-configuration is really fragile imo. Bumping/removing/adding a library can easily change crucial behavior of your application and unless you keep track of the effective auto-configuration you might not even notice until it has gone into production.

Comment: Here were are in 2021, still \@EnableWebMvc will still totally destroy the fragile Spring auto-configuration.  I needed one simple resourceHandler for a location on the filesystem.  So, I implemented a WebMvcConfigurer  and used a @Configuration annotation as seen in the answer below https://stackoverflow.com/a/25878939/1181043

Answer (score 103):

Unlike what the spring-boot states, to get my spring-boot jar to serve the content:
I had to add specifically register my src/main/resources/static content through this config class:

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    private static final String[] CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = {
            "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/",
            "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations(CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same issue, same version of Spring Boot but this didn't work for me either

Comment: Fixed my problem in version 1.2.5!!
thank you so much.. vote this up!!

Comment: This hack works... weird that the auto configuration fails

Comment: Regrettably, this hack doesn't work for me which is a shame due the elegance.
I am not sure if the root cause is the paths to the resource. Perhaps, since I am running it in windows, they need to be formatted differently?

Comment: Notice that WebMvcConfigurer is deprecated now

Comment: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer is not deprecated (Spring-webmvc-5.3.3.jar) .  This solution still works, except I used it to add an additional handler/path combo  "/reports/**", "file:/mnt/somedir/reports/"  Have to keep the slashes on the ends for Linux

Answer (score 52):

I had a similar problem, and it turned out that the simple solution was to have my configuration class extend `WebMvcAutoConfiguration`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class ServerConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration{
}
```

I didn't need any other code to allow my static content to be served, however, I did put a directory called `public` under `src/main/webapp` and configured maven to point to `src/main/webapp` as a resource directory. This means that `public` is copied into `target/classes`, and is therefore on the classpath at runtime for spring-boot/tomcat to find.

Comment: With this way static resources not working in another profiles. for example I have a profile for release that use another IP address. I get 404 error for all of my resources.

Answer (score 29):

Look for Controllers mapped to "/" or with no path mapped.

I had a problem like this, getting 405 errors, and banged my head hard for days. The problem turned out to be a `@RestController` annotated controller that I had forgot to annotate with a `@RequestMapping` annotation. I guess this mapped path defaulted to "/" and blocked the static content resource mapping.

Comment: Solved it for me! I had a controller annotated with @RestController("/blubb") which is obviously wrong, but somestimes you don't see the wood for the trees. Changing it to @RestController
@RequestMapping("/blubb") solved it

Comment: I'm glad it helped, and amused by the notion that the expression "Can't see the woods for all the trees" exists in german as well as swedish :)

Comment: You can also explicitly add @RequestMapping("/") if the intent is to both serve static content and to have a dynamic handler for root requests.

Comment: I have a controller method mapped to "/". But what solved my problem is to add auto config in main class. EnableAutoConfiguration
SpringBootApplication

Comment: Wow....Spent 2 wasted days on this one.  My spring boot mvc application uses spring security and was not seeing the styles.css file.  I believe the security was not allowing the .jsp's to access the styles.css file.  I had a @RequestMapping({"","/", "/home"}) in my controller.  Took out the "" and "/" and my MVC started working perfectly...Very Strange.

Comment: @Shafiul No Adding both EnableAutoConfiguration and SpringBootApplication is redundant! "@SpringBootApplication" contains the "@EnableAutoConfiguration"

Answer (score 22):

The configuration could be made as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter {

// specific project configuration

}
```

Important here is that your `WebMvcConfig` **may** override `addResourceHandlers` method and therefore you need to explicitly invoke `super.addResourceHandlers(registry)` (it is true that if you are satisfied with the default resource locations you don't need to override any method).

Another thing that needs to be commented here is that those default resource locations (`/static`, `/public`, `/resources` and `/META-INF/resources`) will be registered only if there isn't already a resource handler mapped to `/**`.

From this moment on, if you have an image on `src/main/resources/static/images` named `image.jpg` for instance, you can access it using the following URL: `http://localhost:8080/images/image.jpg` (being the server started on port 8080 and application deployed to root context).

Comment: It is perhaps important to comment that although you /can/ override addResourceHandlers, you don't actually need to in order to solve the OP's problem.

Comment: @EngineerDollery thanks for the comment, that was my intention but I explicitly added the explanation

Comment: I moved my css/js into the src/main/resources/static folder and the errors are no longer there, but I'm still not able to to get the css to display in my page.

Comment: Dude, I traveled the depths of the internet to find this working solution. It seems the key was the combination of `@EnableWebMvc` and `WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter`. Thanks big time!

Comment: It didn't work out of the box for me either. I had to add this as well. I just add my commentary here because I had two problems. I also had a controller that mapped "/" as @Johannes mentions. Doing this and removing my "/" controller solved my problems.

Answer (score 13):

I was having this exact problem, then realized that I had defined in my application.properties:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/var/www/static
```

Which was overriding everything else I had tried. In my case, I wanted to keep both, so I just kept the property and added:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=file:/var/www/static,classpath:static
```

Which served files from src/main/resources/static as localhost:{port}/file.html.

None of the above worked for me because nobody mentioned this little property that could have easily been copied from online to serve a different purpose ;)

Hope it helps! Figured it would fit well in this long post of answers for people with this problem.

Comment: I am using Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE and putting `spring.resources.static-locations=file:/var/www/static,classpath:static` into my application.properties, but it did not work for me. I am using `@EnableWebMvc` on my configuration class.

Comment: This was the one that solved my issue. along with `security.ignored` and `security.publicPaths`

Answer (score 11):

Did you check the [Spring Boot reference docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)?

> By default Spring Boot will serve static content from a folder called `/static` (or `/public` or `/resources` or `/META-INF/resources`) in the classpath or from the root of the ServletContext.

You can also compare your project with the guide [Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), or check out the source code of the [spring-boot-sample-web-ui](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui) project.

Comment: Yes I did, those are the places I tried, just as instructed by the docs. But nothing works. I don't get why the resource is not found at all. I've tried to look into the samples, oddly there's no sample that uses the structure proposed by the docs. The one you've just pasted uses a templates folder, I'm assuming that is for a thymeleaf config or velocity.

Comment: The Web UI sample (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/v1.1.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-ui) serves static content.

Comment: I agree with @ViniciusCarvalho, I have tried every combination possible to get the css/js in the right place and can't seem to do that. Even if I visit localhost:8089/css/styles.css i don't see anything. I only have a single rule to change the body color.

Answer (score 7):

I think the previous answers address the topic very well. However, I'd add that in one case when you have Spring Security enabled in your application, you might have to specifically tell Spring to permit requests to other static resource directories like for example **"/static/fonts"**.

In my case I had "/static/css", "/static/js", "/static/images" permited by default , but /static/fonts/** was blocked by my Spring Security implementation.

Below is an example of how I fixed this.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
.....
    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/", "/fonts/**").permitAll().
        //other security configuration rules
    }
.....
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This solution works for me:

First, put a resources folder under webapp/WEB-INF, as follow structure

```
-- src
  -- main
    -- webapp
      -- WEB-INF
        -- resources
          -- css
          -- image
          -- js
          -- ...
```

Second, in spring config file

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(
            DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resource/**").addResourceLocations("WEB-INF/resources/");
    }
}
```

Then, you can access your resource content, such as
http://localhost:8080/resource/image/yourimage.jpg

Answer (score 6):

Just to add yet another answer to an old question... People have mentioned the `@EnableWebMvc` will prevent `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` from loading, which is the code responsible for creating the static resource handlers.  There are other conditions that will prevent `WebMvcAutoConfiguration` from loading as well.  Clearest way to see this is to look at the source:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java#L139-L141

In my case, I was including a library that had a class that was extending from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` which is a condition that will prevent the autoconfiguration:

```
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.class)
```

It's important to *never* extend from `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`.  Instead, extend from `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`.

UPDATE:  The proper way to do this in 5.x is to implement WebMvcConfigurer

Comment: WebMvcConfigurerAdapter is deprecated as of Spring Boot 5.0.  Googling it turns up this in the Javadocs for that class:  "as of 5.0 WebMvcConfigurer has default methods (made possible by a Java 8 baseline) and can be implemented directly without the need for this adapter."  So I *think* one implements WebMvcConfigurer now.

Comment: @Marvo that is exactly right.  The proper way to do this in 5.x is to implement `WebMvcConfigurer`.

Answer (score 4):

Put **static resources** under the directory:

```
/src/main/resources/static
```

add this property in application.properties file

```
server.servlet.context-path=/pdx
```

You can access from http://localhost:8080/pdx/images/image.jpg

[image]

Comment: I don't know how to say **Thanks** to you. Brother you are great. I tried almost all the solutions above but this is the best one and the shortest.

Comment: With files store in static folder: **/src/main/resources/static**
You can define simple like this: `server.servlet.context-path=/`. And use like below: `<img src="logo.png">`

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things to consider (Spring Boot v1.5.2.RELEASE)- 
1) Check all Controller classes for @EnableWebMvc annotation, remove it if there is any
2) Check the Controller classes for which annotation is used - @RestController or @Controller. Do not mix Rest API and MVC behaviour in one class. For MVC use @Controller and for REST API use @RestController

Doing above 2 things resolved my issue. Now my spring boot is loading static resources with out any issues.
@Controller => load index.html => loads static files.

```
@Controller
public class WelcomeController {

    // inject via application.properties
    @Value("${welcome.message:Hello}")
    private String message = "Hello World";

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home(Map<String, Object> model) {
        model.put("message", this.message);
        return "index";
    }

}

index.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>index</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />


    <link rel="stylesheet/less" th:href="@{/webapp/assets/theme.siberia.less}"/>

    <!-- The app's logic -->
    <script type="text/javascript" data-main="/webapp/app" th:src="@{/webapp/libs/require.js}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        require.config({
            paths: { text:"/webapp/libs/text" }
        });
    </script>



   <!-- Development only -->
     <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/webapp/libs/less.min.js}"></script>


</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Removing @EnableWebMvc did it for me! Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2 and not getting any of my static content. I discovered two solutions that worked for me:

**Option #1 - Stop using `@EnableWebMvc` annotation**
This annotation disables some automatic configuration, including the part that automatically serves static content from commonly-used locations like `/src/main/resources/static`. If you don't really need `@EnableWebMvc`, then just remove it from your `@Configuration` class.

**Option #2 - Implement `WebMvcConfigurer` in your `@EnableWebMvc` annotated class and implement**`addResourceHandlers()`
Do something like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class SpringMVCConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/js/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/css/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/vendor/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/vendor/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/");
    }

}
```

Just remember that your code is now in charge of managing all static resource paths.

Answer (score 2):

In case the issue surfaces when launching the application from within an IDE (i.e. starting from Eclipse or IntelliJ Idea), and using Maven, the key to the solution is in the [Spring-boot Getting Started](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) documentation:

> If you are using Maven, execute:
>
> `mvn package && java -jar target/gs-spring-boot-0.1.0.jar`

The important part of which is adding the **`package`** goal to be run before the application is actually started. (Idea: `Run` menu, `Edit Configrations...`, `Add`, and there select `Run Maven Goal`, and specify the `package` goal in the field)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue in spring boot 2.1.3 saying that resource not found 404. I removed below from **applicatiion.properties**.

```
#spring.resources.add-mappings=true
#spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:static
#spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/**,
```

Removed  **@enableWebMVC** and removed any WebMvcConfigurer overriding

> //@EnableWebMvc

Also make sure you have **@EnableAutoConfiguration** in your config.

And put all static resources into **src/main/resources/static** and it just worked like magic finally..

Comment: my spring version in 2.2.6 and I have @EnableAutoConfiguration and files under src/main/resources/static but it doesn't work and throws 500.

Answer (score 2):

Requests to /** are evaluated to static locations configured in
[resourceProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ResourceProperties.html).

adding the following on application.properties, might be the only thing you need to do...

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/myresources/
```

this will overwrite default static locations, wich is:

```
ResourceProperties.CLASSPATH_RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { "classpath:/META-INF/resources/",
        "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };
```

You might not want to do that and just make sure your resources end up in one of those default folders.

Performing a request:
If I would have example.html stored on /public/example.html
Then I can acces it like this:

```
<host>/<context-path?if you have one>/example.html
```

If I would want another uri like `<host>/<context-path>/magico/*` for files in classpath:/magicofiles/* you need a bit more config

```
@Configuration
class MyConfigClass implements WebMvcConfigurer

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/magico/**").addResourceLocations("/magicofiles/");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using 1.3.5 and host a bunch of REST-services via Jersey implementation. That worked fine until I decided to add a couple of HTMLs + js files.
None of answers given on this forum helped me. However, when I added following dependency in my pom.xml all the content in *src/main/resources/static* was finally showing via browser:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
<dependency>
```

It seems spring-web / spring-webmvc is the important transitive dependency that makes spring boot auto config turn on.

Answer (score 1):

**FYI:** I also noticed I can mess up a perfectly working spring boot app and prevent it from serving contents from the static folder, if I add a bad rest controller like so

```
 @RestController
public class BadController {
    @RequestMapping(method= RequestMethod.POST)
    public String someMethod(@RequestParam(value="date", required=false)String dateString, Model model){
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

In this example, after adding the bad controller to the project, when the browser asks for a file available in static folder, the error response is '*405 Method Not Allowed*'.

Notice paths are not mapped in the bad controller example.

Answer (score 1):

using spring boot 2.*, i have a controller that maps to routes `GetMapping({"/{var}", "/{var1}/{var2}", "/{var1}/{var2}/{var3}"})` and boom my app stop serving resources.

i know it is not advisable to have such routes but it all depends on the app you are building (in my case, i have no choice but to have such routes)

so here is my hack to make sure my app serve resources again. I simply have a controller that maps to my resources. since spring will match a direct route first before any that has variable, i decided to add a controller method that maps to `/imgaes/{name}` and repeated same for other resources

```
@GetMapping(value = "/images/{image}", produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE, MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody
    byte[] getImage(@PathVariable String image) {
        ClassPathResource file = new ClassPathResource("static/images/" + image);
        byte[] bytes;
        try {
            bytes = StreamUtils.copyToByteArray(file.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new ResourceNotFoundException("file not found: " + image);
        }
        return bytes;
    }
```

and this solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case I have a spring boot application which is kind of mixing spring and jaxrs. So I have a java class which inherits from the class `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig`. I had to add this line to the constructor of that class so that the spring endpoints are still called: `property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true)`.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem, using gradle and eclipse and spent hours trying to figure it out.

No coding required, the trick is that you must use the menu option New->Source Folder (NOT New -> Folder) to create the static folder under src/main/resources.  Don't know why this works, but did new -> source folder then i named the folder static (then source folder dialog gives an error for which you must check: Update exclusion filters in other source folders to solve nesting). The my new static folder I added index.html and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Well sometimes is worth to check did you override the global mappings by some rest controller. Simple example mistake (kotlin):

```
@RestController("/foo")
class TrainingController {

    @PostMapping
    fun bazz(@RequestBody newBody: CommandDto): CommandDto = return commandDto

}
```

In the above case you will get when you request for static resources:

```
{
    title: "Method Not Allowed",
    status: 405,
    detail: "Request method 'GET' not supported",
    path: "/index.html"
}
```

The reason for it could be that you wanted to map `@PostMapping` to `/foo` but forget about `@RequestMapping` annotation on the `@RestController` level. In this case all request are mapped to `POST` and you won't receive static content in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Given resources under src/main/resources/static,
if you add this code, then all static content from src/main/resources/static will be available under "/":

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourcesConfigurer implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/resources/static/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, some static files were not served, like .woff fonts and some images. But css and js worked just fine.

Update: A much better solution to make Spring Boot serve the woff fonts correctly is to configure the resource filtering mentioned in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34037051/spring-boot-font-awesome-ots-parsing-error-failed-to-convert) answer, for example (note that you need both includes and excludes):

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>static/aui/fonts/**</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>static/aui/fonts/**</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

----- Old solution (working but will corrupt some fonts) -----

Another solution was to disable suffix pattern matching with `setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false)`

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        // disable suffix matching to serve .woff, images, etc.
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
    }
}
```

Credits: @Abhiji did point me with 4. in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

Works for Thymeleaf, you can link the stylesheet using

```
    <link th:href="@{/css/style.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply look at your project log.
For example, put this on your properties:

```
#Log Levels
logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG
logging.level.com.howtodoinjava=DEBUG

# Log Thresolds
logging.threshold.console=TRACE
logging.threshold.file=INFO

# Log to File
logging.file=${java.io.tmpdir}/app.log

# Log Patterns
logging.pattern.console= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} - %msg%n
logging.pattern.file= %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%
```

Later run your app and look you log output, in my case I have that:

```
 None of the document roots [src/main/webapp, public, static] point to a directory and will be ignored.
```

**Solution**: create a folder called: '**webapp**' or '**public**' or '**static**' at level of 'main' folder.

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA COMMUNITY .

I created a folder called "webapp" and had to convert it as "Resources Root".:

[image]

*Inside of this folder I created only my static folder that contains css, js, pics, icons etc.. for you html page use normally your '**resources**' folder by default.*

1. On html page with Thymelef I used :

> ```
> <img th:src="@{/static/profile-pics/pic7.png}">
> ```

2. On html pure I used

> ```
> <img src="/static/profile-pics/pic7.png" />
> ```

The output in console is this :

[image]

**Works fine!!!**

**ATTENTION!!**

[Do not use the `src/main/webapp` **directory** if your application will be packaged as a jar. Although this directory is a common standard, it will only work with war packaging and it will be silently ignored by most build tools if you generate a jar.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.10.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-developing-web-applications.html#boot-features-spring-mvc-static-content)

**If You use only jar as packaged, do nothing and put only this in your properties:**

```
 spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/static/**
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth mentioning that static content would not load for me because I omitted the *args* argument from my main class. Basically, this...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class alpha {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(alpha.class);
  }

}
```

...should be this...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class alpha {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(alpha.class, args);
  }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

As said above, the file should be in `$ClassPath/static/images/name.png`, (/static or /public or /resources or /META-INF/resources). This $ClassPath means `main/resources` or `main/java` dir.

If your files are not in standard dirs, you can add the following configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/lib/**"); // like this
}

@Autowired
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        // ... etc.
}
...
```

}