# Serving index.html content for folder request with Spring Boot MVC

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

Help me please, I am trying to make spring application to serve static content and database api requests, so here is my main class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EntityScan(basePackages = { "domain" })
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = { "repository" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "configuration" })
public class Application {
    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(Application.class);
    private static Class<Application> applicationClass = Application.class;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(applicationClass, args);
    }
}

package configuration;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "controller" })
public class ServerConfiguration extends WebMvcAutoConfiguration {
}

package configuration;

@Configuration
public class RestRepositoryConfiguration extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(RepositoryRestConfiguration config) {
        super.configureRepositoryRestConfiguration(config);
        config.setBasePath("/api");
    }
}
```

How can I make spring response with static/folder/index.html on folder/index.html response?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot not serving static content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content)

Comment: @jny edited my question