# Spring Boot and generated JavaScript/CSS content

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, post-processing

I'm trying to migrate a Spring/Maven application to Spring Boot.  It uses a maven plugin to generate some JavaScript (in my case [handlebars-maven-plugin](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java/tree/master/handlebars-maven-plugin)).

This plugin essentially produces generated JavaScript code that should be included in the deployment artifact.  However, this "**generated code**" is not itself part of the source code.  In the old style Maven web application this content was created in **target** directory as part of the web application folder.

I can imagine other similar situations where some part of the source code is processed as part of the build without the resultant files of this process being part of the source code itself (*minification*, *aggregation*, *obfuscation*, *SASS*, *Less* etc.).

I've read that in Spring Boot static content should be stored in somewhere in the classpath under */META-INF/resources/*, */resources/*, */static/*, */public/*.  But where should generated content be output?

I can change the output directory of the plugin to "/target/classes/static" but when running **mvn spring-boot:run** I cannot locate the generated content.  I presume the "mvn spring-boot:run" is reading the source code from "*src*" rather than "*target*".

How should generated JavaScript/CSS be dealt with in Spring Boot?

Comment: Are you sure that plain file, for example src/main/resources/static/hello.js is visible when started by `spring-boot:run`?

Comment: Thanks @michaldo that helped.  I think I've worked it out now.  I will post my solution later.

Answer (score 2):

I am certain that my generated JavaScript/CSS files should not be written to the **src** directories.  Generated content belongs only in the **target** directory - even if that generated code is included in the distribution artifact (war/jar file).

My confusion was due to two issues.

**"mvn spring-boot:run" behaviour**

My application builds a war file as I have a current requirement to install it on a remote Tomcat server.  [The behaviour of "*mvn spring-boot:run*" is different for jar and war packaging.](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-boot/boot-exploded-war/)  From what I have read, if you have a *war* package "*mvn spring-boot:run*" will attempt to serve web content from the *src/main/webapp* directory.  My generated content does not belong in the *src* directory - so somehow I need to get it served from the *target* directory.

**Confusion about how Spring Boot serves up static content**

[I read that Spring Boot automatically serves up content from several classpath locations](https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot); */META-INF/resources/*,*/resources/*,*/static/*,*/public/*.

Even when I updated my generated JavaScript plugin output path to target a classpath location I initially couldn't locate it.

I ascertained that *WebMvcAutoConfiguration* contains the code responsible for adding the static content paths and that *WebMvcAutoConfiguration* is triggered if your configuration extends *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter*.

However, [I've seen comments to suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content/33852040#33852040) that if you use *@EnableWebMvc* then this effectively disables theses default static content locations (I would value a authoritative reference for this - *I found this now see Update below*).

I used *@EnableWebMvc* so to get around this problem I extended *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter* to explicitly define the static locations to include the classpath folder where I have output my generated content.

I dare say that as I now extend *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter* that I probably don't need to use *@EnableWebMvc* anymore but I'm not yet 100% certain about this.

Now I have explicitly configured the generated content to be located (by overriding *addResourceHandlers* method of *WebMvcConfigurerAdapter*) I am now able to locate this content when using "*mvn spring-boot:run*".

Problem solved - if not completely understood!

---

**Update**

I found the section of the Spring Boot documentation that relates to why you disable the default static content locations when you use @EnableWebMvc, it says:

> The easiest way to take complete control over MVC configuration is to
>   provide your own @Configuration with the @EnableWebMvc annotation.
>   This will leave all MVC configuration in your hands.

It is from the section entitled "[Switch off the Default MVC configuration](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#howto-switch-off-default-mvc-configuration)".