# Spring Boot doesn't serve HTML after Spring Security is enabled

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

In my Spring Boot application, I configure Spring Security as

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  @Override
  public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/images/**", "**/index.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/**.html").permitAll()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login"), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
        .addFilterBefore(new TokenFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);
  }
}
```

I have `index.html` under `resources/static/index.html`. This stopped serving after I enabled security. What am I missing?

If I go back when I do not have any security, I get my HTML rendered on server.

Comment: Does .antMatchers("/*.html").permitAll() work for you? I was under the impression that ** is for directories and * for characters: http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/AntPathMatcher.html

Comment: that does not work either

Comment: Did you annotate your `WebSecurityConfig` class with `@Configuration`? And show your `LoginFilter` and `TokenFilter`.

Comment: And what response do you get? 401, 403 or ...

Answer (score 0):

try to change to `/**/index.html`. For Ant path matcher

```
? matches one character
* matches zero or more characters
** matches zero or more directories in a path
{spring:[a-z]+} matches the regexp [a-z]+ as a path variable named "spring"
```

Comment: nope, there is somethings about the order I guess which is wrong

Comment: You can debug in `org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy#doFilterInternal` to watch all the filter chains. or you can enable the spring security debugger to watch the logger.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same issue. I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content) to solve basic static content issue where adding a configuration class that extends WebMvcConfigurer solved that issue.

But it was just a `@Configuration` bean.

When I changed it to `@EnableWebMvc` as mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/WebMvcConfigurer.html), static content loaded after enabling Spring Security.

Interestingly when I had both annotation, it didn't work.