# Having a catchall request mapping in a contoller exclude resources

Tags: java, spring, controller, resources

I have a default spring mvc application. In it, I have a controller like so:

```
@GetMapping("/**")
public String get(Model model) { }
```

Now this works for all requests, so that's fine, but it also works for static resources like js, img, css files.

How can I exclude these resources? I am using annotations btw..

What I have tried so far:

WebConfig:

```
  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    super.addResourceHandlers(registry);
    registry.addResourceHandler("/images/**").addResourceLocations("/images/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/WEB-INF/css/");
    registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/js/");
  }

  @Override
  public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.enable();
  }
```

WebInitializer:

```
public class WebInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
  }

  @Override
  protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
    return new Class[]{WebConfig.class};
  }

  @Override
  protected String[] getServletMappings() {
    return new String[]{"/"};
  }
```

But it doesn't work, and the request for a `css` file will be handled by the controller instead of showing me the static resource.

As I am not using Spring boot, the solutions mentioned in the linked question did not solve this for me.

Comment: Do you want to serve the static resources or not? What do you expect to get for `http://localhost:8080/images/head.png` - the image itself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring Boot not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content)

Comment: Yes, the static content!