# index.html is not showing up (Request method 'GET' not supported)

Tags: java, spring-boot

**Note:** The code can be found here: https://github.com/silentsnooc/ema-server

---

So, I am cleaning up a quite messy project in which I try to serve static content as well as a small REST API. However, the application gets started as any other:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class Server {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Server.class, args);
    }
}
```

The REST API works for me but the web client is not. I've moved the web client resources into `src/main/resources/static/`

[image]

However, if I visit http://localhost:8080 what I get is 405 (Request method 'GET' not supported).

```
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:207) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:374) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:314) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:61) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:352) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1145) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:936) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897) ~[spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970) [spring-webmvc-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
...
```

I do not understand what's missing - maybe I got the folder structure wrong?

Please let me know if you need any further information from my side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html) `@RestController` is itself annotated with `@ResponseBody` which makes the response of your `RequestMapping` methods to be their return value. In your case that is the `index.html` string you're seeing in the web browser.

Replacing the `@RestController` annotation with `@Controller` should do the trick.

---

As for your error you have another class `WordEmbeddingRestController` which defines mappings for "/" as well, as "/" (or "" to be exact) is the default path value. Removing the `@RestController` annotation from this class will enable you to GET the desired html file.

---

Ignore that, `GET` is the default method if non was specified

<s>For your edit:</s>

You have to add the method you want to support to the `@RequestMapping` annotation for each of your methods. See [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestMapping.html#method--) for more information. As an example:

```java
@RequestMapping(path = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

Instead of using `@RequestMapping` with an explicit method you can also use shorthand annotations like `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping`. Using these would reduce your code to someting like this:

```java
@GetMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "index.html";
}
```

Comment: That definitely sounds correct. However, visiting http://localhost:8080 will still give me back a 405 error .. The log message (on the server) would be `Request method 'GET' not supported`

Comment: Do I actually need this `index()` endpoint? Shouldn't the application serve that by default? It's said that it looks automatically in `static/`, `public/`, etc in order to look for such content.

Comment: In any case: I just tried `GetMapping("/")` - unfortunately with the same result. :/

Comment: Btw. I have pushed the code to https://github.com/silentsnooc/ema-server

Comment: You do not actually need the mapping if you just want to serve static files. You only need it if you (as an example) want to fill in a template file instead of always serving the same static file. As for your error you have another class `WordEmbeddingRestController` which defines mappings for "/" as well, as "/" (or "" to be exact) is the default path value. Removing the `@RestController` annotation from this class will enable you to `GET` the desired html file.

Comment: Thank you! I'll check this out later this afternoon and let you know! :) A refactoring mistake from my side ..

Comment: Thanks - that was in fact the problem. It works now!