# SpringBoot, Thymeleaf, Gradle: not accessing static resources, css not showing

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, static, resources, thymeleaf

I have tried so many things at this point, but my css will not show on my pages. this is my thymeleaf page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title th:text="${title}">Default Title</title>
    <link th:href="@{/css/styles.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

</head>
```

this is the error i get when I load this page, which i assume it important:

```
**2018-04-11 05:57:08.425  WARN 7904 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/css/styles.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'**
```

I have my static resources in the PROPER folder, like this (image link):

[Folders path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMV1C.png)
sources>main>resources>static and then another css folder, which i did add to the @{}.

I have searched and search everywhere for answers, I even added this to my WebMcvConfigurerAdapter class, like I kept seeing:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

This is my current one(im using interceptors and stuff, just disregard that part):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyAppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(new ProjectManagerInterceptor());
    }
}
```

This is my build.gradle file, in case it helps:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.10.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'org.launchcode'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.session:spring-session')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

bootRun {
    addResources = true
}
```

I have another project that also uses static resources like i'm trying to do, and it works perfectly. I will post some of it's code and information, in case it might help.

### Working application's information

CONSOLE WHEN I LOAD A PAGE WITH STATIC RESOURCES:

```
2018-04-11 05:53:15.553 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/css/bootstrap.css]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.554 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /css/bootstrap.css
2018-04-11 05:53:15.554 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/css/techjobs.css]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.554 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /css/techjobs.css
2018-04-11 05:53:15.556 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/css/bootstrap.css]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.556 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/css/bootstrap.css] are [/**]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.558 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/css/bootstrap.css] are {}
2018-04-11 05:53:15.559 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/css/bootstrap.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@3f0bd4d8]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-04-11 05:53:15.560 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/css/bootstrap.css] is: -1
2018-04-11 05:53:15.580 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/js/bootstrap.js]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.581 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /js/bootstrap.js
2018-04-11 05:53:15.582 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/js/bootstrap.js]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.582 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/js/bootstrap.js] are [/**]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.582 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/js/bootstrap.js] are {}
2018-04-11 05:53:15.582 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/js/bootstrap.js] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@3f0bd4d8]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-04-11 05:53:15.582 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/js/bootstrap.js] is: -1
2018-04-11 05:53:15.592 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/css/techjobs.css]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.594 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/css/techjobs.css] are [/**]
2018-04-11 05:53:15.595 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/css/techjobs.css] are {}
2018-04-11 05:53:15.595 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/css/techjobs.css] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [ResourceHttpRequestHandler [locations=[ServletContext resource [/], class path resource [META-INF/resources/], class path resource [resources/], class path resource [static/], class path resource [public/]], resolvers=[org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver@3f0bd4d8]]] and 1 interceptor
2018-04-11 05:53:15.595 DEBUG 7448 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/css/techjobs.css] is: -1
```

HTML:

```
<head th:fragment="head">

    <!-- Bootstrap stylesheets and script -->
    <link th:href="@{/css/bootstrap.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link th:href="@{/css/techjobs.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" th:src="@{/js/bootstrap.js}"></script>

    <title th:text="'TechJobs' + ${title == null ? '' : ' :: ' + title}">TechJobs</title>
</head>
```

FOLDER SETUP:
[Working app's folder paths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMGxz.png)

If there are any questions dont hesitate to ask! I'm really bummed out about this, so much time

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer to my own question, so I'm going to leave this hear for anyone who might find it.

[Spring Boot not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content/33852040#33852040)

I had an unnecessary @EnableWebMvc annotation, that I took out, and my resources worked :D!