# Spring Boot 2 not serializing LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, jackson2

I recently tried to implement a micro service using spring-boot 2.

Now, whenever I attempt to return an object which contains a `java.time.LocalDateTime` from my REST service, the LocalDateTime get serialized as an array of integers. Like so:

```js
{
  "id": "5bf1425f9f8de267f04b22ad",
  "description": "aaaaaarrrgggghhhhh",
  "timestamp": [
    2018,
    11,
    18,
    11,
    43,
    43,
    889000000
  ],
  "time": 2.25,
  ...
}
```

I have tried configuring the `ObjectMapper` through settings in `application.yml`

```
spring:
  jackson:
    serialization:
      write-dates-as-timestamps: false
```

but doesn't work. I have also tried configuring a new ObjectMapper through a Spring Configuration class, like so:

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public ObjectMapper objectMapper(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder builder) {
    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = builder.build();
    objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);
    return objectMapper;
  }
}
```

My configuration gets loaded (debugger stops at a breakpoint) - it's just that it does nothing.

I tried adding `jackson` dependencies manually (also for the jsr310 module) to my pom.xml - also without any luck.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

For some reason it looks like Spring Boot is ignoring my attempts to anything with the ObjectMapper, and it keeps returning the same result.

Setting log level to DEBUG for `com.fasterxml` in the `application.yml` also yields no output:

```
logging:
  level:
    com.fasterxml: DEBUG
```

I use Spring Boot 2.1.0-RELEASE with Jackson 2.9.7.

The basic pom file was generated from https://start.spring.io My project compiles for and runs on a Java 8 JVM.

Comment: did you try to create an ObjectMapper instead of passing a builder to method args and then build a new one based on it? mapper = new ObjectMapper() and then customize it

Comment: Just created a demo project with spring-initializr, (Java 8, Maven, Web support). I ddn't do anything other than add a controller and a simple class with a LocalDateTime property, and I can't reproduce. Are you sure you don't have other dependencies that would change the configuration of Jackson?

Comment: Do you have `@EnableWebMvc` on one of your `@Configuration` classes? If so, remove it. It fights with the spring boot way of configuring spring mvc.

Comment: @JBNizet I think you may be on to something. For this project I'm using mongodb - it may be that the spring-starter-mongo serializer/deserializer is the culprit - I'll get back when I have tried to remove it.

Comment: @teppic +1 Bingo that was the problem - now I hope my Cors config still works... Too bad I can't accept your response as a solution.  :)

Comment: @teppic If you create a "proper" response, I will accept that as the answer, since it was your comment that got me on the right track.

Comment: @MartinJesRasmussen: just tick your self answer. If you're interested, there are some other questions with the same cause that have answers with more detail (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51065174/3591528)).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer is based on teppic's comment to the original post.

The issue was caused by @EnableWebMVC on one of my @Configuration classes. Removed @EnableWebMVC immediately solved the problem.

Comment: Thanks! In the absence of ‘@EnableWebMVC' I found this also occurs if you’re manually initialising MockMVC in your tests. e.g., MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(controller)... Using ‘@AutoConfigureMockMvc' with an autowired MockMvc fixes this.

Answer (score 3):

From your comments I found the issue as you blend the `@EnableWebMvc` with sprongboot. It turns out that Spring Boot doesn’t mix well with the standard Spring MVC `@EnableWebMvc`. What happens when you add the annotation is that spring boot autoconfiguration is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You must add jsr310 support to jackson :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Looks helpful. It’s not my home field, but I was under the impression that it’s been replaced by [jackson-modules-java8](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-modules-java8)? The link does contain dependencies for for Spring.

Comment: Should have written, that I already tried that. Also, I can see that jsr310 is indeed included as a transient dependency.