# @EnableWebMvc "disables" Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer how to fix?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jackson

I have confiured annotation introspector ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48801237/1251549))

```
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomBigDecimalDeserialization() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.annotationIntrospector(
                    new JacksonAnnotationIntrospector() {
                        @Override
                        public JsonPOJOBuilder.Value findPOJOBuilderConfig(AnnotatedClass ac) {
                            if (ac.hasAnnotation(
                                    JsonPOJOBuilder.class)) {//If no annotation present use default as empty prefix
                                return super.findPOJOBuilderConfig(ac);
                            }
                            return new JsonPOJOBuilder.Value("build", "");
                        }
                    }
            );
        }
    };
}
```

And everything works until I added `@EnableWebMvc` to `Applciation` class. Now all dtos which have lombok `@Value` and `@Builder` annotations are fileld with nulls. It seems that my annotation introspector was replaced some where by spring. But where? Spring [boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-the-jackson-objectmapper) said that it is enough to define `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer` bean.

Any ideas how configure/fix setting annotation introspectors with `@EnableWebMvc`?

Comment: Don't add `@EnableWebMvc`. Spring boot sets up spring mvc automatically without it. Similar problems discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53364800/spring-boot-2-not-serializing-localdatetime#comment93640725_53364800) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51065174/3591528).

Comment: Add this as en anwser.

Answer (score 0):

Let's first understand why we need to use @EnableWebMvc.
Spring traditionally supports two types of configurations:

[XML based configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.5/reference/xsd-config.html)

[Annotation based configuration](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_annotation_based_configuration.htm)

So if we want spring to support annotation we add @EnableWebMvc. But
if we are using Spring Boot, it will auto-configure the equivalent of @EnableWebMvc for you. Unless you want to switch off all of Boot's opinions about how Spring MVC should be configured, you should not use @EnableWebMvc in your application.

Now in your case by giving a Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer you want jackson to customize the behavior but @EnableWebMvc is switching off any opinion your object mapper is providing.