# Spring 5 not serving static content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following file structure:

[image]

the `MvcWebConfig` file has this:

```
@Configuration
public class MvcWebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**")
                .addResourceLocations("/public", "classpath:/static/")
                .setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }
}
```

as read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33852040/2636044) that `@EnableWebMVC` shouldn't be used.

I've tried this in my HTML (which is placed in the templates folder)

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

but none of these worked.

What am I doing wrong? I'm using Spring 5

Comment: check in browser network tab that from where it is trying to load the files.

Comment: `http://localhost:8080/` + any of these `static/css/bootstrap.min.css, /resources/static/css/bootstrap.min.css, css/bootstrap.min.css`

Answer (score 0):

It can be maven that blocks your resources from being copied to your jar.

Resources to be copied are set in your pom.xml, for exemple :

```
<build>
    <finalName>app</finalName>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>application*.yaml</include>
                <include>dozer_mapping.xml</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Check if your resources are correctly copied in your build.