# Serving static content results in Request method 'GET' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-security, thymeleaf

I want to serve static content from my static directory in my project resources, but I get error: org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported.

I have added configured Spring Security to ignore requests starting with "/static/". I have added resource handler to WebMvcConfig to look for the static content in various different locations, I have tried removing the resource handler altogether.

I have tried adding permitAll() to the "/static/" path.

I have googled the error message and various combinations of it to find solutions. This is where I came up with the Spring Security and WebMvcConfigs. Just that these did not solve the problem for me.

Finally I have tried placing static files into different locations. The directory structure is as follows:

```
\resources\static\hello.css
\resources\static\css\hello.css
\resources\templates\home.html
\resources\templates\error.html
```

Thymeleaf works correctly, taking the templates from the templates directory.

The WebMvcConfig:

```java
// Config Thymeleaf
private static final String VIEWS = "classpath:templates/";

@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    return resolver;
}

private ISpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    return engine;
}

private ITemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver resolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    resolver.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
    resolver.setPrefix(VIEWS);
    resolver.setSuffix(".html");
    resolver.setTemplateMode(TemplateMode.HTML);
    return resolver;
}

// Enable static resources
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/static/**")
            .addResourceLocations("/resources/static/", "classpath:static/", "/static/", "classpath:resources/static");
}
```

The Spring Security config:

```java
@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web
        .ignoring()
        .antMatchers("/static/**");
}
```

I expect to see my css file, but instead I see the error page generated by exception handler with the message "Request method 'GET' not supported"

Here is the debug trace from the point I request the css file:

```
2019-06-07 11:30:29.694 DEBUG 5398 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request : '/static/css/hello.css'; against '/static/**'
2019-06-07 11:30:29.694 DEBUG 5398 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /static/css/hello.css has an empty filter list
org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' not supported
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.handleNoMatch(RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.lookupHandlerMethod(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:419)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:365)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.getHandlerInternal(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:65)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMapping.getHandler(AbstractHandlerMapping.java:401)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.getHandler(DispatcherServlet.java:1232)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1015)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:882)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:209)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:200)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:836)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1747)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: How are you trying to access your css file? Do you've a controller?

Comment: @Jorge.V There are multiple controllers but none for the static files themselves, as I have understood they are not needed with static files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After hours of debugging I found the reason static content was not served!
It was because of a controller with mapping without the path:

```java
@PostMapping()
```

After adding a path to the mapping, the configuration above works as it should.
Very weird that it messed up the serving of static files!

Big thanks to @Ganesh for his tip in [Spring Boot not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was having the same issue today. and the Spring error message is not that clear.

Answer (score 1):

thanks @Avaruuskadetti you saved hours of my time

DEBUG:
package org.springframework.web.servlet >>>> HandlerExecutionChain

```
protected HandlerExecutionChain getHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
    if (this.handlerMappings != null) {
        Iterator var2 = this.handlerMappings.iterator();

        while(var2.hasNext()) {
            HandlerMapping hm = (HandlerMapping)var2.next();
            if (this.logger.isTraceEnabled()) {
                this.logger.trace("Testing handler map [" + hm + "] in DispatcherServlet with name '" + this.getServletName() + "'");
            }

            HandlerExecutionChain handler = hm.getHandler(request);
            if (handler != null) {
                return handler;
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```