# Springboot does not serve static content

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am not able to access static content (angular app) or even a simple index.html file from spring-boot. I keep getting 404 error. Spring is not serving me with those static files. I have the problem since I have upgraded to Spring-Boot 2.2.4. I had to upgrade to counter Zip64 issue.

I have this line in my application.properties:

```
spring.resources.static-locations=classpath:/resources/,classpath:/static/
```

I also have my own staticResourceConfiguration class.

In my WebSecurity class, i have the following which is supposed to serve static content if the url path is matched to the below patterns. The problem is localhost:8080/index.html works and localhost:8080 return 404

```
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/**","/**/*.html", "/static/favicon.ico", "/**/*.js", "/**/*.js.map", "/**/*.css", "/**/*.png", "/**/*.jpg", "/**/*.jpeg", "/**/*.gif", "/**/*.ttf", "/**/*.json", "/**/*.woff", "/**/*.woff2", "/**/*.eot", "/**/*.svg","/**/*.json").permitAll()
```

Comment: spring-boot-starter-web just verify you are using this dependency. We no need to configure if your file under static directory.

Comment: Yes I have it under my dependency list.

Comment: Where is your index.html (in project)???

Comment: it is under resources>static>index.html. This sub-folder contains the an angular 7 built app. When I debug it works perfectly. It is only when I build a jar from spring-boot that things are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this answer to improve your own
[Spring Boot not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content)

or this

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations("file:/path/to/staticPage/");
    }
}
```