# Using openapi.yaml in springdoc

Tags: swagger, springdoc

I can customize OpenAPI from [code](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#can-i-customize-openapi-object-programmatically).
Can I do same over openapi.yaml like [swagger-petstore](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-petstore/blob/master/src/main/resources/openapi.yaml)
I create simple springboot project with one @RestController.
I create openapi.yaml and copy it to /src/main/resources/.
But I see default values on open swagger-ui page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below is all what we needed to do to use `openapi.yaml` specification file instead of the default one that is generated from code.

Explanation:

- `org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource` is Controller that handles `/v3/api-docs` and `/v3/api-docs.yaml` endpoints. Swagger UI is using that endpoint to show swagger ui page - `/swagger-ui.html`. You can see the configuration when you hit `/v3/api-docs/swagger-config` endpoint.
- `org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource` bean is registered only if missing. You can see it in `SpringDocWebFluxConfiguration`. The method that creates the bean is annotated with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean`. So you just need to extend it and adjust OpenApi specification retrieval (see below).
- `org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource` is using `getOpenApi()` method to retrieve OpenAPI specification (by default the specification is generated based on the class annotation from code). So you just need to override `getOpenApi()` method and provide the specification from yaml file itself (`getYamlMapper()` method is also provided for you in the parent classes, so it's really that easy how it is in the file below)
- You can see `OpenApiResource` is in `webflux` package because we use `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-webflux-ui`, Spring WebFlux. It is done similarly in Spring MVC.
- Hope this helps :) When you hit `/swagger-ui.html` you should see the docs directly from .yaml spec. When you hit `/v3/api-docs` you should see the specs itself in JSON. When you hit `/v3/api-docs.yaml` you should see the specs itself in YAML. No Spring Configuration code is needed. Just the controller as you see below :)
- Just to be clear. Our OpenAPI spec is in `src/main/resources/openapi/api.yaml`

---

```
package com.your.package;
...imports omitted for readability...
import org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiResource;

@RestController
public class OpenApiController extends OpenApiResource {

  @Value("classpath:openapi/api.yaml")
  private Resource openAPIResource;

  private OpenAPI openAPI;

  public OpenApiController(ObjectFactory<OpenAPIBuilder> openAPIBuilderObjectFactory, AbstractRequestBuilder requestBuilder, GenericResponseBuilder responseBuilder, OperationBuilder operationParser, RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping requestMappingHandlerMapping, Optional<List<OperationCustomizer>> operationCustomizers, Optional<List<OpenApiCustomiser>> openApiCustomisers, SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties, Optional<ActuatorProvider> actuatorProvider) {
    super(openAPIBuilderObjectFactory, requestBuilder, responseBuilder, operationParser, requestMappingHandlerMapping, operationCustomizers, openApiCustomisers, springDocConfigProperties, actuatorProvider);
  }

  @SneakyThrows
  @PostConstruct
  public void initOpenAPI() {
    openAPI = getYamlMapper().readValue(openAPIResource.getInputStream(), OpenAPI.class);
  }

  @Override
  protected synchronized OpenAPI getOpenApi() {
    return openAPI;
  }
}
```

Comment: I was also thinking about it if it is or not. But OpenApiResource method is annotated with @ConditionalOnMissingBean bean so I think that was the intention. To let you freely configure it if you need :)

Definitely better than making HTTP redirections and registering custom resource handlers for the specification.

Comment: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springdoc.core.AbstractRequestService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

Answer (score 16):

This is available from the FAQ page in the spring-doc documentation.
See [What is a proper way to set up Swagger UI to use provided spec.yml?](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_what_is_a_proper_way_to_set_up_swagger_ui_to_use_provided_spec_yml) and [How can use custom json/yml file instead of generated one ?](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_how_can_use_custom_jsonyml_file_instead_of_generated_one) of the same page.

Example from the FAQ page

1. Turn off auto-generation in the project property file `springdoc.api-docs.enabled=false`
2. Put your yaml file in `src/main/resources/static` such as `src/main/resources/static/myApiFile.yaml`
3. Set the swagger-ui url for the file `springdoc.swagger-ui.url=/myApiFile.yaml`
4. Enable the minimal beans configuration

```java
import org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties;
import org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class SpringDocsConfiguration {

  @Bean
  SpringDocConfiguration springDocConfiguration() {
    return new SpringDocConfiguration();
  }

  @Bean
  public SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {
    return new SpringDocConfigProperties();
  }
}
```

Comment: this is the way I chose, and it works. This answer needs to get the links updated as they do not point to the correct location.

Comment: not working for me

Comment: doesn't work for me

Comment: It could be that the static file is not correctly served by Spring Boot. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24661289/6409815

Comment: What would be the URL then in this case to access the doc?

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70059281/21556046) is excellent and lead me to the right direction. I applied all steps but the code section had a difference with the [link provided](https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_what_is_a_proper_way_to_set_up_swagger_ui_to_use_provided_spec_yml). In the link provided the code suggested contains also an `ObjectMapperProvider` which is absent in that answer.

Also once the changes are applied the endpoint to verify the modification that worked for me was `http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html`

Hope this helps clarify, but all the information is already there. Thanks.

```
import org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties;
import org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfiguration;
import org.springdoc.core.providers.ObjectMapperProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

/**
 * Provides the capabilities to display the apiDoc in a preconfigured endpoint based on the following information of open-api
 * https://springdoc.org/faq.html#_what_is_a_proper_way_to_set_up_swagger_ui_to_use_provided_spec_yml
 * This apiDoc can be consulted through the endpoint: http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html
 */
@Configuration
public class SpringDocsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    SpringDocConfiguration springDocConfiguration() {
        return new SpringDocConfiguration();
    }

    @Bean
    public SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties() {
        return new SpringDocConfigProperties();
    }

    @Bean
    ObjectMapperProvider objectMapperProvider(SpringDocConfigProperties springDocConfigProperties){
        return new ObjectMapperProvider(springDocConfigProperties);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need configuration file, you can have a look at the FAQ, documentation:

- https://springdoc.org/faq.html#can-i-use-spring-property-with-swagger-annotations

And here is the link for code samples:

- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/master/springdoc-openapi-webmvc-core/src/test/java/test/org/springdoc/api/app15/SpringDocApp15Test.java

Comment: Thanks, I know how did it from java code. I search way how to configure it only with YAML-file, without java code.

Comment: @YuraShinkarev, did you find the answer?

Comment: @SashaKorkin, no

Answer (score 0):

This kotlin-based comes out from ...webflux-ui:1.6.0:, hope It useful for someone:

```
import io.swagger.v3.core.util.Json
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI
import lombok.SneakyThrows
import org.springdoc.core.AbstractRequestService
import org.springdoc.core.ActuatorProvider
import org.springdoc.core.GenericResponseService
import org.springdoc.core.OpenAPIService
import org.springdoc.core.OperationService
import org.springdoc.core.SpringDocConfigProperties
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OperationCustomizer
import org.springdoc.webflux.api.OpenApiWebfluxResource
import org.springdoc.webflux.core.SpringDocWebFluxConfiguration
import org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectFactory
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigureBefore
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Primary
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpRequest
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import java.util.*
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct

@Profile("!test")
@AutoConfigureBefore(SpringDocWebFluxConfiguration::class)
@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
class OpenApiConfig {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun openApiResourceCustom(
        openAPIBuilderObjectFactory: ObjectFactory<OpenAPIService>,
        requestBuilder: AbstractRequestService,
        responseBuilder: GenericResponseService,
        operationParser: OperationService,
        operationCustomizers: Optional<MutableList<OperationCustomizer>>,
        openApiCustomisers: Optional<MutableList<OpenApiCustomiser>>,
        springDocConfigProperties: SpringDocConfigProperties,
        actuatorProvider: Optional<ActuatorProvider>
    ): OpenApiWebfluxResource {
        @RestController
        class CustomOpenApiController(
            openAPIBuilderObjectFactory: ObjectFactory<OpenAPIService>,
            requestBuilder: AbstractRequestService,
            responseBuilder: GenericResponseService,
            operationParser: OperationService?,
            operationCustomizers: Optional<MutableList<OperationCustomizer>>,
            openApiCustomisers: Optional<MutableList<OpenApiCustomiser>>,
            springDocConfigProperties: SpringDocConfigProperties,
            actuatorProvider: Optional<ActuatorProvider>
        ) : OpenApiWebfluxResource(
            openAPIBuilderObjectFactory,
            requestBuilder,
            responseBuilder,
            operationParser,
            operationCustomizers,
            openApiCustomisers,
            springDocConfigProperties,
            actuatorProvider
        ) {
            @Value("classpath:openapi/spec.json")
            private lateinit var openAPIResource: Resource
            private lateinit var openAPI: OpenAPI
            override fun getServerUrl(serverHttpRequest: ServerHttpRequest, apiDocsUrl: String): String {
                val requestUrl = decode(serverHttpRequest.uri.toString())
                val prefix = findPathPrefix(openAPIService.context, springDocConfigProperties)
                return requestUrl.substring(0, requestUrl.length - apiDocsUrl.length - prefix.length)
            }

            @SneakyThrows
            @PostConstruct
            fun initOpenAPI() {
                openAPI = Json.mapper().readValue(openAPIResource.inputStream, OpenAPI::class.java)
            }

            override fun getOpenApi(locale: Locale?): OpenAPI {
                return openAPI
            }
        }

        return CustomOpenApiController(
            openAPIBuilderObjectFactory, requestBuilder,
            responseBuilder, operationParser, operationCustomizers,
            openApiCustomisers, springDocConfigProperties, actuatorProvider
        )
    }
}
```