# SpringBoot serving static images from custom Path

Tags: java, spring-boot, staticresource

As now I've always served my images through a static path in the `application.properties` file:

```
spring.resources.staticlocations=file:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/reportMaker/template
spring.mvc.static-path-pattern=/resources/**
```

Then by doing

```
http://localhost:8080/resources/logo.png
```

I'm able to reach the logo.

Now my aim is to switch with a folder path taken from my DB.

I've tried this approach:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

@Autowired
ConfigurationRepository confRepo;

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

    myConfiguration conf = confRepo.findByConfKey("downloadPath");
    String path =  conf.getConfValue();

    if(path !=null) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations(path);
    }
}
```

But I can't reach the logo in same way as before.

The path variable is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/reportMaker/template`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spring Boot not serving static content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24661289/spring-boot-not-serving-static-content)

Comment: Try to place the logo at src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/ and drop that springboot config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved by removing: `@EnableWebMvc` and adding a `/` at the end of my path

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("file:/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/reportMaker/template/");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> The path variable is `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/reportMaker/template`.

According to this documentation https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources the path should be prefixed by `file:/`